# Existence of the tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces. Lets also consider the set $F$ the functions $\xi:E_1\times E_2\to \mathbb{K}$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\{(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\in E_1\times E_2: \xi(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\not=0\}|<\infty
\end{equation}
and lets denote by $(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v}):=1_{(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})}$. It is clear that $F$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space with the usual pointwise operations.

Now consider the vector space $G$ generated by the following vectors
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
(\lambda\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})-\lambda(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})\\
(\mathbf{u}|\lambda\mathbf{v})-\lambda(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})\\
(\mathbf{u}_1+\mathbf{u}_2|\mathbf{v})-(\mathbf{u}_1|\mathbf{v})-(\mathbf{u}_2|\mathbf{v})\\
(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v}_1+\mathbf{v}_2)-(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v}_1)-(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v}_2)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
for all $\mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{u}_1$, $\mathbf{u}_2\in E_1$, $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2\in E_2$ and for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$.

Let $\alpha:E_1\times E_2\to E$, being $E$ an arbitrary $\mathbb{K}$-vector space, a bilinear map.

> Is the map $\Phi_\alpha:F/G\to E$ the map defined by
>   $\Phi_\alpha([(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})]):=\alpha(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$
>   well defined?

I tried to prove this by seeking for some characterization for the equivalence of vectors of $F$, but I only cound find that $[(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})]=[(\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{u}|\lambda\mathbf{v})]$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\}$ and was unable to prove this is the only possibility.

Comment: Show that there's a linear map $\phi_\alpha \colon F \to E$ with $G \subseteq \ker \phi_\alpha$.  Then $\Phi_\alpha$ is the factoring of $\phi_\alpha$ through the quotient map $F \to F/G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matthew pointed out, lets define the linear map $\phi_\alpha(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v}):=\alpha(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$, which is defined for every vector in $F$ because $F$ is the span of all the $(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})$ functions.

It is clear that $G\subset\ker\phi_\alpha$ as long as all the generators of $G$ lie in $\ker\psi_\alpha$. It is also clear that $\phi_\alpha=\Phi_\alpha\circ \pi$, where $\pi:F\to F/G$ is the quotient projection.

So, if $(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})\sim(\mathbf{u}'|\mathbf{v}')$, then $(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})-(\mathbf{u}'|\mathbf{v}')\in G$, and therefore
\begin{equation}
\Phi_\alpha([(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})])=\phi_\alpha(\mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v})=\phi_\alpha(\mathbf{u}'|\mathbf{v}')=\Phi_\alpha([(\mathbf{u}'|\mathbf{v}')])
\end{equation}

so $\Phi_\alpha$ is well defined.